# Convertir texto en json: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo el siguiente texto:

```
"{'monto':{'bounds':{'vertices':[{'x':0.88398695,'y':0.89646465},{'x':0.9722222,'y':0.89646465},{'x':0.9722222,'y':0.905303},{'x':0.88398695,'y':0.905303}]},'page':-1,'startLocation':0,'endLocation':0},'identificacion':{'bounds':{'vertices':[{'x':0.05882353,'y':0.89646465},{'x':0.09477124,'y':0.89646465},{'x':0.09477124,'y':0.905303},{'x':0.05882353,'y':0.905303}]},'page':-1,'startLocation':0,'endLocation':0},'nombre':{'bounds':{'vertices':[{'x':0.12908497,'y':0.89520204},{'x':0.30882353,'y':0.89520204},{'x':0.30882353,'y':0.905303},{'x':0.12908497,'y':0.905303}]},'page':-1,'startLocation':0,'endLocation':0}}"
```

y quisiera convertirlo a un json, al usar JSON.parse(), me devuelve el error: Unexpected ' token o in JSON at position 1. Cómo puedo convertir el texto?

Comment: Creo que tendras que cambiar las comillas simples por comillas doble para que te funcione con el metodo `JSON.parse()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que no tengas que reemplazar todas las comillas simples a dobles manualmente, te recomiendo uses [JSON5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json5)

Y lo puedes usar de la misma manera como usas `JSON.stringify` y `JSON.parse` así:

```html
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/json5/dist/index.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var str = "{'monto':{'bounds':{'vertices':[{'x':0.88398695,'y':0.89646465},{'x':0.9722222,'y':0.89646465},{'x':0.9722222,'y':0.905303},{'x':0.88398695,'y':0.905303}]},'page':-1,'startLocation':0,'endLocation':0},'identificacion':{'bounds':{'vertices':[{'x':0.05882353,'y':0.89646465},{'x':0.09477124,'y':0.89646465},{'x':0.09477124,'y':0.905303},{'x':0.05882353,'y':0.905303}]},'page':-1,'startLocation':0,'endLocation':0},'nombre':{'bounds':{'vertices':[{'x':0.12908497,'y':0.89520204},{'x':0.30882353,'y':0.89520204},{'x':0.30882353,'y':0.905303},{'x':0.12908497,'y':0.905303}]},'page':-1,'startLocation':0,'endLocation':0}}";
    console.log(JSON5.parse(str));
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Funciona si remplazas las comillas simples por dobles en tu string:

```js
const e = `{"monto":{"bounds":{"vertices":[{"x":0.88398695,"y":0.89646465},{"x":0.9722222,"y":0.89646465},{"x":0.9722222,"y":0.905303},{"x":0.88398695,"y":0.905303}]},"page":-1,"startLocation":0,"endLocation":0},"identificacion":{"bounds":{"vertices":[{"x":0.05882353,"y":0.89646465},{"x":0.09477124,"y":0.89646465},{"x":0.09477124,"y":0.905303},{"x":0.05882353,"y":0.905303}]},"page":-1,"startLocation":0,"endLocation":0},"nombre":{"bounds":{"vertices":[{"x":0.12908497,"y":0.89520204},{"x":0.30882353,"y":0.89520204},{"x":0.30882353,"y":0.905303},{"x":0.12908497,"y":0.905303}]},"page":-1,"startLocation":0,"endLocation":0}}`


console.log(JSON.parse(e))
```

Comment: Esas no son "comillas" simples, son [templates strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings).

Comment: Revisa bien: cambiar de esto `'monto': ` a esto: `"monto": `.

Comment: @VickMuñoz es correcto lo que dice Merling, las comillas simples no son válidas en JSON. El JSON original ha sido creado usando esas comillas.

Comment: @A.Cedano Cierto, no me había dado cuenta en esa modificación, se me paso de largo, aunque podría también quitar las comillas dobles, después utilizar JSON.stringify() y después usar JSON.parse()

Comment: @VickMuñoz, ya, pero si se crea de origen el JSON como es debido se evita luego marearlo con tantas conversiones y el peligro que eso supondría (errores de conversión/codificación, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Un poco tarde ya, pero tambien esta la opcion de usar `replace` para reemplazar todas las comillas simples por dobles.

```js
const unparsedJson = "{'monto':{'bounds':{'vertices':[{'x':0.88398695,'y':0.89646465},{'x':0.9722222,'y':0.89646465},{'x':0.9722222,'y':0.905303},{'x':0.88398695,'y':0.905303}]},'page':-1,'startLocation':0,'endLocation':0},'identificacion':{'bounds':{'vertices':[{'x':0.05882353,'y':0.89646465},{'x':0.09477124,'y':0.89646465},{'x':0.09477124,'y':0.905303},{'x':0.05882353,'y':0.905303}]},'page':-1,'startLocation':0,'endLocation':0},'nombre':{'bounds':{'vertices':[{'x':0.12908497,'y':0.89520204},{'x':0.30882353,'y':0.89520204},{'x':0.30882353,'y':0.905303},{'x':0.12908497,'y':0.905303}]},'page':-1,'startLocation':0,'endLocation':0}}";

const formattedJson = unparsedJson.replace(/'/g, `"`);
const parsedJSON = JSON.parse(formattedJson);

console.log(parsedJSON);
```